# Fat Arrow Functions in Netbeans 8.1?

Tags: node.js, netbeans, syntax-error

I think it's not recognizing the fat arrow function. It complains like this:

[image]

Only when I modify my code from `(err, stats) => {` to `function(err, stats){` then the error disappears.

Is there a way to fix this or my only option is to supress this type of errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't know that people still use Netbeans, but Netbeans [doesn't support ES6 syntax](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242387) yet, but it might be close according to one of the comments:

> Guys, I have to apologise. The parser based on Antlr doesn't suffer from performance problems like a month ago, but the memory consumption is still high. We run in problems in ANTLR 4 runtime itself and we are working with antlr authors to solving these issues. I can not guess what time it will take.
>
> In parallel  I have taken a close source parser and currently I'm
>   trying to work with this one. Unfortunately it's close source and we
>   have to go through licensing  process, where I don't have any doubts
>   how it long it can take. When I get the permission to put the parser
>   to our hg, then there will be available build and hopefully with a few
>   implemented ECMA 6 features.

Comment: I switched to Atom for a while but modifying syntax highlighting was time consuming and couldn't make SFTP with a key to work to connect to Amazon EC2. Was glad when found out that Netbeans 8.1 incorporated NodeJS, but if it doesn't support ES6 it's kinda frustrating since NodeJS is quick to adopt as many of ES6 features as possible.

Comment: @MarinaDunst try Webstorm I have never used it, but I'm almost pretty sure that setting sftp is quite easy and you can use the [EAP version](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP) for free,

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans 8.2 now supports ECMA6 syntax https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/relnotes.html#new